# How to manage 3D array initialization with many pages?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically  initializing a **3D** `array`(static initialization), which have  around **200** pages.
It takes more than 1000+ lines :

```
int[][][] array3D= new int[][][]
{
    { {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} 
    },

    { {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

...
...
...200 pages
```

The code looks a mess.I want to avoid `loop`s to save time.Any clear work around I can follow?Also it takes lot of code space.Any better way using files too ?

**UPDATE: Why not loops?**

Because this is something un-related logic.

For EG, consider 9 queen problem(they should be placed in such a way on chess board that they don't kill each other)  .This problem have *94* solutions with an array struct something like `QueensSolution[8][8][94]`. This array have to be initialized manually .

Comment: why you wanna avoid loops?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne Because of the code complexity and time constraints.

Comment: What kind of time constraints?

Comment: I don't think there might be huge time difference that you can gain by this way rather than using loops. And for me, this looks even complex than a simple set of loops

Comment: Have you actually measured the performance of a loop or are you just making an excuse up based on wild guesswork?

Comment: @joeyrohan: Do you have sufficient profiling numbers to prove that loops are noticeably slower than your hand-rolled code?

Comment: Not to mention that if time really is essential (which I doubt in this case), multi-dimensional arrays aren't the best choice of storage.

Comment: The array looks simple enough from what I can see, you could have it generated on initialization and it would probably not take any more time than loading and processing the array. You have to do that in linear time anyway.

Comment: @joeyrohan Why don't you then put your arrays in a text file and read that and initialize through that. But it is more time consuming coz it deals with file IO. But it will be much more cleaner code

Comment: I have a strong feeling we're facing a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: write a script that outputs the source code you need.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne may be that's only the option left.

Comment: Though File approach is much cleaner, going for a file IO is comparatively very much slower than your current approach. Anyway it is up to you.

Comment: Why is the speed of initialisation critical? That's a rather strange constraint. Usually it's the other way around. Reading all your configurations from a file is the straightforward thing to do.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I was thinking to create a dummy class just for the array . Would work but silly.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma yeah, I calculated the millis time for both cases :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to put the whole array in your code, I suggest you put it in a header file and then include it in your source.

But again, as suggested in the comments, the performance of a loop is not much different, and anyway, because of the initialization happening only once on start up, the difference would not be significant.